# Different type of authentication for the same controller

Tags: c#, jwt, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I have WEB API CORE 3.0 back-end application. Its controllers are protected with Azure AD. 
For this I Use microsoft identity web library.

In the source code I configure it like this:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("Configuring services");
        services.AddProtectedWebApi(Configuration, subscribeToJwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents: true)
            .AddProtectedApiCallsWebApis(Configuration)
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
...
```

And to protect controller I use [Authorize].

Everything works perfect.

Now I want to add the second way to authorize users (along with Azure AD).
I want that users be able to login either with Azure AD or, say, JWT.

Is it possible to implement it for the same controller?

Comment: Authentication is per *web app*, not controller. The code you posted affects the entire app, not just a single controller. `Authorize`, as the name suggests, affects authorization (whether an already authenticated user is allowed to do something or not)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I know. [Authorize] is to make controller methods callable only for authorized users. Is it possible to change the existing authorizing mechanism to allow non-AzureAD users to use the controller. Where should I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the existing authorizing mechanism to allow non-AzureAD users to use the controller.

Sounds like you're trying to make the `[Authorize]` to allow multiple authentication scheme at the same time. If that's the case, you should firstly register those authentication scheme with `AddAuthentication().AddMyScheme1().AddMyScheme2()...`:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
    .AddJwtBearer(otps=>{
        otps.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters{ ...};
    });
```

And then change the default Authorization Policy to authenticate those authentication schemes at the same time. For example, if you want to allow Identity/JwtBearer/AzureAd at the same time, you could do it in following way

```
services.AddAuthorization(opts =>{
    opts.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(
            IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme     // ASP.NET Core Identity Authentication
            ,JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme // JwtBearer Authentication
            // ,"AzureAD"                           // AzureAd Authentication
        )
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});
```

Or if you want to allow only specific user/Role further, feel free to custom it by :

```
opts.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(
        IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme     // ASP.NET Core Identity Authentication
        ,JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme // JwtBearer Authentication
        // ,"AzureAD"                           // AzureAd Authentication
    )
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .RequireRole(...)
    .RequireAssertion(ctx =>{
        ...
        return true_or_false;
    })
    .Build();
```

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461398/how-to-make-azuread-and-custom-jwt-tokens-to-work-side-by-side-in-web-api helped